# Find more than X elements in a 1:n:m database relation using Django ORM

Tags: sql, django, orm, count, group-by

I have four Django models: User, Project, Task, TaskResult. Now, given a user, I want to count the results the user submitted to each project and return a task (any one) of the project where the user submitted fewer than X results.
As the number of TaskResults is very large, I cannot do this in memory - it should all be SQL.

(This is my first question ever, so please bear with me if anything is wrong with it. I've been searching a solution for the whole day now and could't find one - most probably because I find it difficult to ask the right question.)

I've tried aggregations, annotations, F's, Q's and whatnot, but it didn't work out. Now, I wrote a raw-query which (I am pretty sure) would do the job:

```
SELECT crowd_task.id
FROM crowd_project
LEFT JOIN crowd_task ON crowd_task.project_id=crowd_task.id
LEFT JOIN crowd_taskResult ON crowd_taskResult.task_id=crowd_task.id
WHERE crowd_taskResult.user_id=23
GROUP BY crowd_project.id
HAVING COUNT(crowd_taskResult.task_id) < 3
LIMIT 0,1
```

This SQL query is tested and works.

Here is an example:
There is one user (id=23) and two projects P1 and P2.
P1 has four tasks: T11, T12, T13 and T14.
P2 has two tasks: T12, T22.
Now the user starts submitting results. Since the maximum number of results the user should submit is 3 (see above SQL), in the beginning the query should always return any of the tasks of P1. Assuming the user has now submitted results to T11, T12 and T14, she should *not* solve T13. Instead, the query should return any of the tasks of P2.
(btw: there is also a check whether all tasks have been solved by this user - I omitted this for simplicity.)

Looks pretty straightforward, doesn't it? I would really like to use the ORM whenever possible, but I have no clue how to get this done.

Comment: Provide a sample of data and desired results.  This is also a good way to help you understand what you are trying to do in terms of data manipulation.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! The example is now in the text. I am using RawQuerySets for now, but this will probably not work for other databases than MySQL...

Comment: Your query doesn't use anything 98% of database engines out there won't support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django's ORM does not support `HAVING`. Since `HAVING` is the correct way to do this, you must use a raw query.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! As far as I know from [tis question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13344182/how-to-implement-the-having-clause-in-sqlite-django-orm) HAVING can be achieved with aggregations in Django. According to the ticket at [Django](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8784) there are still discussions every now and then on whether HAVING should be added to extra(). Anyway, I will settle for raw() now. Many thanks for your help!