# Django equivalent to HAVING in MySQL and filter by model's field

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, orm

I have two tables:

```
table1
 -----------------
|  id  |  salary  |  
|  1   |   2500   |
|  2   |    500   |
 -----------------

table2

 -------------------------------
|  id  |  outlay  |  table1_fk  |  
|  1   |   20     |      1      |
|  2   |   40     |      1      |
|  3   |  1000    |      2      |
 -------------------------------
```

and I need to select all rows from table1 + *sum of outlays* where *salary* is bigger than *SUM of outlays*
the MySQL query would be:

```sql
SELECT t1.*, COALESCE(SUM(t2.outlay),0) AS total_outlay 
FROM table1 AS t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.table1_fk 
GROUP BY t1.id 
HAVING total_outlay < t1.salary;
```

Is it possible with Django ORM? So far I have this:

```py
Model1.objects.filter(somefilterlogic).annotate(outlay_total=Sum("model2__outlay"))
```

---

I'm using Django 2.2.5 and MySQL

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement the having clause in sqlite django ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13344182/how-to-implement-the-having-clause-in-sqlite-django-orm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [**`.filter(…)`** [Django-oc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter) *after* the [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) clause:

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum

Model1.objects.filter(
    somefilterlogic
).annotate(
    outlay_total=Sum('model2__outlay')
).filter(
    total_outlay__lt=F('salary')
)
```

As you say, you can also make use of [**`Coalesce`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce) to use zero in case there are no related `Model2` objects:

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

Model1.objects.filter(
    somefilterlogic
).annotate(
    outlay_total=Coalesce(Sum('model2__outlay'), 0)
).filter(
    total_outlay__lt=F('salary')
)
```

Comment: That's what I needed, I was missing the F function. Also I modified the annotation to correspond exactly with the MySQL query
`Model1.objects.filter(somefilterlogic).annotate(outlay_total=Coalesce(Sum("model2__outlay"), 0)).filter(
    total_outlay__lt=F('salary')
)`