# Django ORM Query with 'having' and 'group by'

Tags: python, sql, django, group-by, django-queryset

This is the raw sql query I'm trying to write in Django ORM.

```sql
    SELECT cf, sum(fee)
        FROM public.report
        where report_date = '2021-11-01'
        group by cf
        having sum(fee) > 500000
```

I've tried this, but I miss the having part:

```py
Report.objects.filter(report_date=date_to).values('cf').annotate(Sum('fee'))
```

I've also tried this, but here I miss the other part to group by fiscal code.

```py
Report.objects.filter(report_date=date_to).aggregate(fee=Sum('fee', filter=Q(fee__gte=50000)))
```

I need to join this 2, to make a unique query.

Answer (score 1):

Django query:

```
Report.objects \
    .filter(report_date=date_to) \
    .values('cf') \
    .annotate(total_fee=Sum('fee')) \
    .filter(total_fee__gte=500000)
```

Result:

```
SELECT "core_report"."cf", SUM("core_report"."fee") AS "total_fee"
FROM "core_report"
WHERE "core_report"."report_date" = 2021-11-01
GROUP BY "core_report"."cf"
HAVING SUM("core_report"."fee") >= 500000
```

[Explanation of what i did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13367962/16004568)